# <Link to=> not switching pages

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, module

I've been working on this dropdown menu for a while but I can't seem to get the dropdown menu to change the page I'm on and I don't understand what's wrong with it I am really new to ReactJs, I have a module called **DropDownMenu** it is calling **DropDownItem** and when **DropDownItem** is clicked is called a function called handle click but in the **HandleClick** it is not switching the page to the current **Props.Route** clicked on and i don't know enough of whats going on to really figure it out

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function DropdownItem(props) {
  const handleClick = () => {
    <Link to={props.route}></Link>;
    console.log(props.route);
  };

  return (
    <a href="#" className="menu-item" onClick={handleClick}>
      <span className="icon-button">{props.leftIcon}</span>
      <span className="Route">{props.route}</span>

      {props.children}
      <span className="icon-right">{props.rightIcon}</span>
    </a>
  );
}

export default DropdownItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just throw a `<Link>` in the middle of a callback function and expect it to do anything when called.

Use the `<Link>` element **instead of** the `<a>` element.

---

Make use of [`useNavigate`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/api.md#usenavigate) if you need to trigger navigation from a callback (which you don't in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can use useHistory hook.you may use to navigate.

when you use react router dom v5

```
      import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

     let history = useHistory();
     const handleClick = () => {
        history.push(`/${props.route}`);
        console.log(props.route);
      };
```

when you use react router dom v5

import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

```
      const navigate = useNavigate();
     const handleClick = () => {
       navigate(`../${props.route}`, { replace: true });
        console.log(props.route);
      };
```

Comment: `useHistory` has [been replaced in the current react router](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/upgrading/v5.md#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory)

Comment: Yeah . You are right.  useNavigate is the solution.